# Error in VSO Release Management

Tags: azure, azure-devops, release-management, ms-release-management

I have created a simple release template using VSO to deploy on an Azure VM. The template has just one simple component to test.

When I start a release, the Accept Deployment and Predeployment steps are done ok.
The deploy step seems to work also, the component is copied to the Azure VM in the C:\Windows\DtlDownloads folder (although I don't have a deployment script yet).

At some moment (I guess at the end of the deploy step) the RM Client pops up a toast with the error: {"ErrorMessage":"'\u001f', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character."}

The deploy step keeps the status Pending forever.
When I try to open the Release in the RM client, I get the same error.

This is the stacktrace from the log file:

```
3/27/2015 11:37:08 AM - Error - (10204, 47808) - {"ErrorMessage":"'\u001f', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character."}: \r\n\r\n   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Common.ExtensionMethods.XmlExtensionMethods.ToXDocument(String value, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Model.ModelFactory.TransformXmlToModel[T](T model, String xml)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Model.ModelFactory.Load[T](Int32 id)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Release.ViewModel.ViewModels.PipelineV2.ReleaseV2ViewModel.RefreshTimerTick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Any idea about the cause of this error?

And how to stop such a pending release? Can't find an option in the client to stop or delete it.

Comment: Di you have a space in your build name?

Comment: Might be worth working through [this](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-vso-configuring-release-management/) to check you have the initial steps configured correctly. Should have the next part published this weekend. Are you deploying a simple demo app or an actual real-world app, as latter tend to be more problematic?

Comment: @MrHinsh: I have one or two spaces in the build name. Could that be the problem? I will check next week.

Comment: @MrHinsh: Without spaces, I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I followed initially the steps in this blog: http://roadtoalm.com/2015/02/04/start-with-visual-studio-release-management-vnextvs-rm-for-dummies/
It skipped the PSScriptPath first to do a kind of dry run.
But that seems to cause the error.
After I created a script and set this property, the error went away.